# SQL subqueries code which return unexpected results: "This query returned no results."

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I tried this SQL subqueries code as per video tutorial but when I run it returned unexpected results: "This query returned no results." I copied word for word including the database table names. There is no problem with the syntax as the database didn't prompting any error message. I attached below the sample code.
P/S: All the table names and its path are correct as per image reference.

```
SELECT
    station_id,
    name
FROM 
    bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations
WHERE 
    station_id IN
    (
        SELECT 
            start_station_id
        FROM 
            bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
        WHERE
            usertype = 'subscriber'
    )
```

the image of code and the return result indicating "This query returned no results" :

[image: 1]

Comment: seems like there is no row in citibike_trips table with usertype = 'subscriber' or no rows in citibike_stations table with returened station_id from subquery

Comment: put some data in rather than attaching an image

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to confirm that there are matching station_ids between those two subqueries. If there are, then you can use common table expression like below.

```
WITH trip_ids AS (
    SELECT start_station_id
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    WHERE usertype = 'subscriber'
)
SELECT station_id, name
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations b
INNER JOIN trip_ids ON b.station_id = trip_ids.start_station_id;
```